# JSON Array + String

Tags: arrays, json

I'm trying to send JSON with one Array of documents:

- fileName
- fileContent

- sting requestID

I already got function JSON for that array but dont know how to add string requestID which is not part of Array
My JSON:

```
  {
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "array",
  "items": [
    {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "fileName": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "fileContent": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "fileName",
        "fileContent"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Sorry to be a pedant, but that's not a json array. That's a json object.

Comment: as @Stewart said, we cannot seem to see any `array` in the `JSON` you provided.

Comment: @Stewart  please be so kind and check now if suits better, I'm new to JSON therefore the syntax imperfections